# How to index a numpy array element with an array

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a numpy array, and would like to get the value at a specific element. For example, I might like to access the value at `[1,1]`

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
print A[1,1]
# 4
```

Now, say I've got the coordinates in an array:

```
i = np.array([1,1])
```

How can I index `A` with my `i` coordinate array. The following doesn't work:

```
print A[i]
# [[3 4 5]
#  [3 4 5]]
```

Comment: `A[tuple(i)]` will work.

Comment: Ahh I figured it'd be simple.. I don't really understand why that works though. Could you perhaps create an answer pointing to the relevant docs?

Comment: Documentation can be found [here](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-0dffc419afa7d77d51062d40d2d84143db8216c2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

> In Python, `x[(exp1, exp2, ..., expN)]` is equivalent to `x[exp1, exp2, ..., expN]`; the latter is just syntactic sugar for the former.

So to get the same result as with `A[1,1]`, you have to index with a tuple.

If you use an `ndarray` as the indexing object, advanced indexing is triggered:

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is `A[tuple(i)]`. The `tuple(i)` call just treats `i` as a sequence and puts the sequence items into a tuple. Note that if your array has more than one dimension, this won't make a nested tuple. It doesn't matter in this case, though.